# Table rows as dropdown

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table. I'm trying to add functionality such that when I click on a row it should display a set of row, just like drop down menu. I have done the following:

```
<table>
    <tr class="clicker">
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Some new data here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$(".clicker").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).next().hasClass("down")) {
        $(this).next().slideUp("normal").removeClass("down");
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideDown("normal").addClass("down");
    }
});
```

When I trying to add a second and third row in the hidden rows like:

```
   <table>
<tr class="clicker">
    <td>some data</td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden">
    <td>Some new data here</td>

</tr>
<tr class="hidden">
    <td>Some more data here</td>

</tr>
```

, it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: what exactly do you want? `When I trying to add a second and third row in the hidden rows like:` do you mean to create new cells inside hidden rows?

Comment: Or do you mean to create new hidden rows?

Comment: @juanpastas what OP means is the slide applies only to one row with 'hidden' as class instead of all rows...
Jishnu you can try my solution and accept if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [example](http://jsbin.com/eraser/1/edit).

```
$('.clicker').click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.clicker').slideToggle('normal');
});
```

It toggles several rows. Also you can easily have several clicker with this way.

Comment: How would you make it so that the initial status of all 'rows' is closed?

Comment: To answer my own question: As I was using classes other than 'hidden', in an FAQ page I made, I had 'question' and 'answer' classes. I simply set `.answer{display:none;}` to initialize collapsed rows by default then @juanpastas JS will take over from there...

Answer (score 1):

you need `siblings` instead of `next`.. 
`next selects only 1 next sibling`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8D6va/)**

```
$(".clicker").on("click", function(){

if($(this).siblings().hasClass("down")){
    $(this).siblings().slideDown("normal").removeClass("down");
}
else{
   $(this).siblings().slideUp("normal").addClass("down");

}
});
```

Or

```
 $(".clicker").on("click", function(){

    $(this).siblings().slideToggle('normal');

});
```